# Как сформировать union запрос в ActiveRecord yii2

Tags: yii2

вот собственно сам запрос

```
SELECT id, name_film, slug_film, created_at FROM `fl_film`)
UNION
 (SELECT id, name_mfilm, slug_mfilm, created_at FROM `fl_mfilm`)
UNION
 (SELECT id, name_serial, slug_serial, created_at FROM `fl_serial`)
ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

как его сформировать запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятно через метод `findBySql`. Подробнее тут: [ссылка на апи](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#findBySql()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы на вашем месте отказался от `UNION`. Не стоит разносить по разным таблицам данные которые должны выводится в одном списке.
Рекомендую посмотреть в сторону PostgreSQL. А для начала почитайте про [Наследование таблиц в Postgresql](https://habrahabr.ru/company/rambler-co/blog/282676/). Для своего проекта когда-то выбрал Single Table Inheritance и ещё ни разу об этом не жалею.